# Magento2 Source selection based on Sellable Quantity

Tags: magento2, msi

I'm trying to modify the Source Selection algorithm based on the following condition:

```
Sort by Sellable(available) Quantity (Descending) and then location sort priority
```

I have tried many tutorials but it's not working, I tried to override the following model `Magento\InventorySourceSelection\Model\Algorithms\PriorityBasedAlgorithm` but not work.
Is there any way to override distance-based and Priority Based Algorithms to my own algorithms?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to add your own algoritms:

https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/php/development/framework/inventory-management/source-selection-algorithms/

You are free to override this class with a preference or modify the method with a plugin too.